# Remove option from dropdownlist in loop

Tags: jquery

I have a two dropdown boxes with ID's: test1 and test2.
I want to dynamically remove some options from them with the code below, but this does not work.

When I change this:

```
$("#test" +i4 "option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

into:

```
$("#test1 option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

it does work.

How can I get the +i4 to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i4 = 1;
while (i4 <= 2) {



$("#test" +i4 "option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();


i4++;
}

</script
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `+` and a space in

```
$("#test" +i4 "option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

should be

```
$("#test" + i4 + " option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a space and + before option[..] :

```
$("#test" + i4 + " option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

it has to be

```
$("#test" + i4 + " option[value='1/21.00/1']").remove();
```

the second "+"-operator for connecting strings was missing